# Manage Missing FDA Drug Labels from New Update Files

Tags: openfda

I am using Drug Labeling [/drug/label] at OpenFDA to ingest the updated files. I understand I need to re-ingest all the files every time there is a release and update the previously built database. My question is about the labels in the previously built database but not in the current ingesting update files, should I keep them? Or those files should be marked as deleted or not used.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome to keep them for your own archival purposes if desired, but Labels are removed for various reasons as new update files are released, with intention, so if your goal is to work with the currently updated labeling data, rebuilding every release and allowing the previous results to delete is the approach I would recommend.

Regards,

Violet Wren, openFDA Tech Lead

Comment: Thank you so much! That answers my question!